# How do I fix Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, build, export, app-store

If you can fix this error I'll give you $5 paypal cause I am actually desperate.

I just spent a bunch of time making a game in unity, and I build and export it to find that after I build the game and get past the unity splashscreen I get the error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xba)". I've been looking for fixes for hours but I can't find anything thats worked so far, please help.

NOTE: I know nothing about swift and im following a youtube video on how to get my unity game on the app store, so I hope this can be resolved by changing a few lines and not fixing this through any complex matter that a newbie would struggle with.

Thanks

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzxNM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, look at the Console window and make sure there are no Exceptions. You code probably has problems, but running in the editor it is continuing past them a little whereas on Android and iOS it will crash to desktop/OS. Most likely the exceptions are in your Console in the editor, fix them all - anything that shows in red text in the Console after you hit the Play button should be fixed.

Comment: The only thing red is the error that shows up during runtime. There is no error that shows up in the console in both xcode and unity.